# Hide a div on hover outside of div

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div id='container'>
    <div id="animate"></div>
</div>
```

I have a small div inside a big div with id container . i want to hide div with id animate if someone hovers the out side of small div . it should remain open when mouse is over the small div .

Comment: Is `animate` hidden by default?

Comment: I assume that the 'small div' is the #animate div?

Comment: StackOverflow is not the proper place for this question. We do not write your code for you. You need to do your own coding and if you aren't sure why something is not working as expected, post the code with an explanation of what you were expecting it to do, and what it is actually doing including all error messages. See [about StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the same effect with pure CSS:

```
#animate {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    transition: opacity 0.2s;
}

#container:hover #animate {
    opacity: 0;
}

#container #animate:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gXz2A/

Answer (score 5):

This should do it

```
$('#small').hover(function () {
    $('#animate').show();
}, function () {
    $('#animate').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

**CSS:**

```
#container{width:100px;height:100px;background:#F00;}
#animate{width:50px;height:50px;background:#0F0;}
```

**Script:**

```
$(function(){
    $('#container').mouseenter(function(){
        $('#animate').fadeTo(1000,0)
                     .mouseenter(function(){$(this).fadeTo(1000,1)});
    }); // use 750 in place of 1000 to animate it fast
});
```

Docs http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/

**HTML:**

```
<div id='container'>
    <div id="animate">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/aZmfz/4/

Comment: (citing OP: ) *it should remain open when mouse is over the small div .*

Answer (score 1):

**HTML:**

```
<div id='container'>
    <div id="animate">HI!</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#container{
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: black; 
}
#animate{
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: white;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("#animate").hover(
    function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, 1000);
    },
    function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, 1000);
    }
);
```

[**EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/KdQRL/)

You may **not** want to do a strict [show](http://api.jquery.com/show/)/[hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/), because the element will have **no height/width** to hover over **when it's hidden**. Instead, you may prefer to **set the opacity to 0 (to hide) or 1 (to show)** and let the [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function transition between the two. You'll also notice that I used the [.stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) function. This is because if you [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) back and forth over the element it will continue to call the queued up animations. Calling [stop](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) first will prevent this.